# Having different locations of objects on a uiview

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have an application that I am making with A `UIDatePicker` and a `UIToolBar` attached to a view. The `UIToolBar` has an animation set to slide up. this is where my problem is. On the iPhone 4 the toolbar needs to finish its animation at a lower position than on the iPhone 5. How do I set the height differently for each device?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can distinguish iPhone 5 from iPhone 4 like this:

```
if([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone && [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height == 568.0){
    //is iPhone 5
}
else{
    //is iPhone 4
}
```

Then, set your UIToolBar's frame appropriately for each screen size.

Also, here's the macro for convenience (put this in your .pch file):

```
#define IS_4_INCH_SCREEN [[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone && [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height == 568.0
```

Answer (score 1):

you should get the screen size first and then use if condition, if the screensize is corresponding the iphone 5  screen and then place accordingly

```
if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 568)
{
// for iphone 5
}

else 
{
 // assume that another option is iphone 4 only,
}
```